# How to refer to local installed Angular2 bundle rather than "npm install" every time?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

While trying different tutorials of Angular2 I realised everytime I have do "npm install" for all packages (`@angular, rxjs, core-js, systemjsm zone.js, lite-serever` and list goes on).

So I am wondering rather then duplicating it each time If I could have them at one local and just refer from there, like node_module folder of project A could be referenced from all the packages mentioned in `package.json` of project B ?

Comment: Finally made it working, defined how here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215280/404-not-found-errors-in-zone-js/45236307#45236307

Answer (score 0):

Referring is not possible.

However there is a workaround to this, You can have your folder structure like this

```
Projects
├── node_modules
├── Project A
├── Project B
├── ├── project files
```

node when searching for local modules goes back a directory if it doesn't find the needed modules in the directory itself. So in this case a common node_modules will be accessible by all your projects

**Warning** : while using this, you have to be very cautious, because if you upgrade packages or something then it may be possible that one of your project which was compatible with package version 3.2.1 may not be compatible with 4.1.1. In above case your that project will go down and you'll go mad finding out the reason why this is happening.

Comment: Okay, & then shall I do "npm install" or ?

Comment: no need to do npm install in every new project. just for the first time you're creating project in that folder.(i.e projects folder)

Comment: If I just do "npm start" it fails since can't recognise "tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" " So still need a work around. Or like a way to point angular lib from here & if required install lite server