# How to share common resources for all angular projects that run locally?

Tags: javascript, angular, zone

I am attempting to set up a local environment to run multiple apps from one directory with common/shared resources.

I have this directory structure (locally):

```
|AngularApps
|-App1
|-App2
    |---app
    |---index.html
    |---tsconfig.json
    |---tslint.json
    |---typings.json
    |---systemjs.config.js
|-node_modules
|-package.json
```

And then I use lite-server in root, hence I have modified the path in systemjs.config.js to:

```
  paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'App2/app',
```

Now when I load the App1 zone.js is not able to find most of my components:

[image]

I couldn't find any topic online pointing to the same.

Idea is to avoid duplicating all resources.

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this in the systemjs.config.js:

```
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      'angularstuffhere':'angularstuffhere'
    },
packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
```

In Index.html

```
<app-root>Loading Client...</app-root>
```

Now create your app.module in the app folder and reference app/App1/app and app/App2/app; which might have components or may be modules themselves. This is what you might need.

If you want two different unrelated apps then do the following in your systemjs.config.js (no need for two systemjs.config):

```
paths: {
          // paths serve as alias
          'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
          // our app is within the app folder
          app: 'App1/app',
          app2: 'App2/app',
          'angularstuffhere':'angularstuffhere'
        },
    packages: {
          app: {
            main: './main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
          rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
```

In Index.html

```
<app1-root>Loading Client...</app1-root>
<app2-root>Loading Client...</app2-root>
```

Update:

Try changing the serving folder of bsconfig.json to the following:

```
"baseDir": "dirofyourapp",
```

Since you have compile issues, change the following in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p dirofyourapp/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p dirofyourapp/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2edirofyourapp/",
```

You will not be able to run to different apps with one set of scripts and you will have to create your own custom scripts in package.json

If you want a reusable code, then create a reusable independent module and use it in your apps by importing rather than creating a complex unmaintainable development environment.

An example of how to create reusable modules that can be used by a lot of apps:

[https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/chart/chart.ts](http://Reusable%20module%20example)

Comment: Hello @Gary are you suggesting to have 1 systemjs.config.js in root and declare the mappings there ?

Comment: Just wanted to tell you how to use different fetch folders. Making two apps is completely your choice. But if you intend to use App1 folder and App2 folder then you will be better off using child modules rather than folder based segregation.

Comment: `are you suggesting to have 1 systemjs.config.js in root and declare the mappings there` yes thats the way to go if app1 and app2 are different apps. Else use child modules. Remember, you have to declare them anyways in ngmodule. there is no way out. whether you do it in child module or parent is a choice you have. I have changed the code to your need.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work @gary either Browsersync or lite-server has issues while transpiling, and not much available on this topic online.

Comment: This is not the way many would structure their apps. The issue is related to pathing and not related to the structure of apps though. The next place I would want you to check is the bsconfig.json and change the folder name it is serving.This is what you should be doing, I believe  `"baseDir": "changetodirtobeserved",`

Answer (score -1):

Finally made it working, posting answer so that a seeker has help.

The solution is to have an empty folder (Home) first, to hold all you common lib for all Angular Projects.

In the Home folder add a package.json and mention all the dependencies that you are going to use in all Angular projects `(an ideal one https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json)`

Now make sure you have a -global install of lite-server (`https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server`) This will be useful to host/run all the projects

Now create a `bs-config.json` in the root, this way we'll scope the localhost, other words tell it which project to run.

Once you have it you can go on with child dir for all apps you want to use under it. No need to change any path in any app.

All shall run smooth.

[image]

Adding more projects:
[image]

Comment: Dont understand you already have a package.json. what you have primarily now is two different projects. Why reinvent the wheel. Use two different quickstarts!

Comment: Should keep only one package.json and in the root, just change the baseDir param to the name of project that you want to run.

Also, tsconfig.json should be kept in root too.

Comment: Yes thats two different project end of day. Why would you to do that? Your question was how to stop duplicating all resources. Thats a unmaintainable solution. If node modules was the resource duplication you talking about and not duplication of code resources of the app may be you wasting too much unknown time changing paths. Just create two projects. Even with ng-cli 130 mb dependencies you have project cleanliness and in todays world of gb and tb, mb is cheaper than your time.